# Add additional characters to strings in file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have `.h` file as below

```
//Structure
typedef struct VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In
{
vbittype unused31 : 8;
vbittype unused30 : 8;
vbittype unused29 : 8;
vbittype unused28 : 8;
vbittype unused27 : 8;
vbittype unused26 : 8;
vbittype unused25 : 8;
vbittype unused24 : 8;
vbittype unused23 : 8;
vbittype unused22 : 8;
vbittype unused21 : 8;
vbittype unused20 : 8;
vbittype unused19 : 8;
vbittype unused18 : 8;
vbittype unused17 : 8;
vbittype VIN_DATA_AH_C : 56;
vbittype unused9_0 : 2;
vbittype VIN_MSG_AH_C : 2;
vbittype unused9_1 : 4;
vbittype unused8 : 8;
vbittype unused7 : 8;
vbittype unused6 : 8;
vbittype unused5 : 8;
vbittype unused4 : 8;
vbittype unused3 : 8;
vbittype unused2 : 8;
vbittype unused1 : 8;
vbittype unused0 : 8;
}__attribute__((packed))_c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_msgType;


//union
typedef union _c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_bufTag
{
    vuint8 _c[32];
    _c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_msgType VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In;
} _c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_buf;


//Declaration
_c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_buf  VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_data;
```

As you see all the type names starts with `_c_`.

```
_c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_msgType
_c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_bufTag
_c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_buf
```

I want to add `_Moto_` tag to them as below.

```
_c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_msgType
_c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_bufTag
_c_VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_buf
```

I have many such definition and common tag I can find in such definition is `_c_`.

Can you please help me with `sed` command to replace all of them in one shot?

Comment: I'm new to `sed` command, I did not get anything regarding adding string, instead got many topics regarding replacing existing string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's always some string between `_c_` and `_In_`, and after `_In_`:

```
sed 's/_c_[[:alnum:]_]*_In_/&Moto_/g' file.h
```

should work. It matches `_c_<zero or more alphanumeric chars and underscores>_In_` and adds `Moto_` after it.